# SAP S/4HANA On-Prem REST API

Tags: sap-erp, sap-cloud-connector

I'm working with the SAP Cloud Application Library and have spun up a fully activated S/4HANA appliance (On Azure). What is the best practice if I want to access the REST APIs (ODATA) that are available for my system? From the research I've done it sounds like the best practice is to use the Cloud Connector, so the calls from the external system are sent to the cloud and the Cloud Connector s used to communicate to the On=Prem system, but wondering if there if there is also a method where you make calls directly to the on-prem server if there is benefits to this architecture.